# Normal vector to a parametric surface $f$ is invariant under equivalent parameterizations

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, solution-verification

My lecture notes define a regular parametric surface as follows:

> Definition 1: Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open such that $\bar{D}$
> is Jordan measurable. Then a map $f: \bar{D} \to \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ is
> regular if
>
> $$rank(df_x) = x \quad \text{for all } x \in D.$$
>
> We call $f: \bar{D} \to \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ an ($n$-dimensional)
> parameterized surface.

The tangent space and the normal vector for the case of $n=2$ and $k=1$ are then defined as follows:

> Definition 2: We call $T_{(x,y)} f =: df_{(x,y)}(\mathbb{R}^2) =$ {$s \partial_1 f(x,y) + t \partial_2 f(x,y)$} $\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ the
> tangent plane to $f$ at $(x,y)$.
>
> Definition 3: We call $N: D \to \mathbb{R}^2, N(x,y) := \frac{\partial_1 f(x,y) \times \partial_2 f(x,y)}{\lVert \partial_1 f(x,y) \times \partial_2 f(x,y) \rVert}$ the normal vector to $f$ at
> $(x,y)$. From the two possible choices for such a  vector, our choice
> is oriented in the sense that $det(\partial_1 f(x,y), \partial_2 f(x,y), N(x,y))$.

My lecture notes also mention that the tangent plane and the normal vector are invariant under equivalent parameterizations ($\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism with $det(d \varphi)>0$). For example, we have $T_{(x,y)} (f \circ \varphi) (\mathbb{R}^2)= T_{\varphi(x,y)} f (\mathbb{R}^2)$ by the chain rule since $d \varphi$ has rank $2$.

Now I am struggling with showing that the normal vector is also invariant under equivalent parameterizations.

Proof idea: We know that $T_{(x,y)} (f \circ \varphi) (\mathbb{R}^2)= T_{\varphi(x,y)} f (\mathbb{R}^2)$, so $\partial_1 f(\varphi(x,y)) \in T_{(x,y)} (f \circ \varphi)$, i.e. $\partial_1 f(\varphi(x,y)) = \alpha_1 \partial_1 (f \circ \varphi)(x,y) + \alpha_2 \partial_2 (f \circ \varphi)(x,y)$. Similarly, $\partial_2 f(\varphi(x,y)) = \beta_1 \partial_1 (f \circ \varphi)(x,y) + \beta_2 \partial_2 (f \circ \varphi)(x,y)$.

This implies that $\langle \partial_1 f(\varphi(x,y)), \partial_1 (f \circ \varphi) (x,y) \times \partial_2 (f \circ \varphi) (x,y) \rangle = 0$ and $\langle \partial_2 f(\varphi(x,y)), \partial_1 (f \circ \varphi) (x,y) \times \partial_2 (f \circ \varphi) (x,y) \rangle = 0$. This means that $\partial_1 (f \circ \varphi) (x,y) \times \partial_2 (f \circ \varphi) (x,y)$ is orthogonal to the tangent space to f at $\varphi(x,y)$ or in other words that $\partial_1 (f \circ \varphi) (x,y) \times \partial_2 (f \circ \varphi) (x,y)$ lies in the orthogonal complement of $T_{\varphi(x,y) f}$, which means that it is parallel to $N_f(\varphi(x,y))$.

Since the normal vector is a unit vector by definition, it remains to show that the orientaion is preserved if $det (d \varphi)>0$.

Consider the special case where $\partial_1 f(\varphi(x,y))$ and $\partial_2 f(\varphi(x,y))$ lie in the xy-plane first. Then $\partial_1 f_3(\varphi(x,y))=\partial_2 f_3(\varphi(x,y))=0$, and so $\partial_1 f(\varphi(x,y)) \times \partial_1 f(\varphi(x,y)) = (0, 0, \partial_1 f_1(\varphi(x,y)) \partial_2 f_2(\varphi(x,y)) - \partial_1 f_2(\varphi(x,y)) \partial_2 f_1(\varphi(x,y)))^T$. Thus,

$$det(\partial_1 f(\varphi(x,y)), \partial_2 f(\varphi(x,y)), N(\varphi(x,y)) = \frac{1}{\lVert \partial_1 f(\varphi(x,y) \times \partial_2 f(\varphi(x,y)\rVert} (\partial_1 f_1(\varphi(x,y)) \partial_2 f_2(\varphi(x,y)) - \partial_1 f_2(\varphi(x,y)) \partial_2 f_1(\varphi(x,y)))^2 = det(dg(\varphi(x)))$$

where $g=(f_1, f_2)^T$.

Now we can see that an equivalent parameterization does not change the sign of the derivative since $det(d (g \circ \varphi)(x)) = det(dg(\varphi(x))) det(d \varphi(x))$, i.e. $det(dg(\varphi(x)))$ and $det(d (g \circ \varphi)(x))$ have the same sign.

1. Is my proof idea correct?
2. How can I show this inthe general case? I think we can simply rotate the partial derivatives, so that we are back in the special case above using rotation matrices. The rotation will be the same before and after the application of $\varphi$ such that the determinant of the rotation matrices does not affect the conclusion above.